# how to use php imagecreatefromwebp library in Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, laravel-5, gd, webp

when I try to use the the php function imagecreatefromwebp() in heroku php app I get an error the function does not exist, I tried to search for documentation to enable that php function but I did not find any.

In my local environment I have this result:
    php --ri gd

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.9.0
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 9 compatible
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.6.34
WBMP Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled
WebP Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

but in heroku environment the GD library is incomplete.

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.6.1
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 8
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.54
WBMP Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

could someone help me to enable that WebP Support. I'm using Laravel 5.5 with composer and php build-pack

Comment: I tried to use this solution but it fails compiling https://github.com/dmcgua01/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick-webp